# Detect IOS version with Cocos2d-X

Tags: cocos2d-x

How can i detect the running IOS version using cocos2d-x?

When i used cocos2d i used the code below but i don't wanna go obj-c++.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Maybe it is possible to use UIDevice with cocos2d-x, i don't know.

Comment: why not check in Objective-C? it is the most native way and Cocos2d-x uses Objective-C to start up your app before it calls `AppDelegate`

Comment: That's not Objective-C++, it's Objective-C.

Comment: and why is that a problem? Have you tried to use one of those `defines`? They work just fine and that is the correct way to check the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your code in appcontroller.mm class. it will work.

already cocos2d-x is checking the version like this for setting viewcontroller

```
// Set RootViewController to window
if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
{
    // warning: addSubView doesn't work on iOS6
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];
}
else
{
    // use this method on ios6
    [window setRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented in cocos2d-x 3.4, is to add the following method in CCApplication-ios.mm

```
float Application::getSystemVersion() {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
}
```

Add this to CCApplication-ios.h

```
/** Get iOS version */
static float getSystemVersion();
```

And call it anywhere by using

```
float systemVersion = Application::getSystemVersion();
```